# How to reuse a WebElement as a locator in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a method that finds and returns WebElements.
I use this method so to keep my code clean and maintainable. That way there is only one location to update if and when the developers change the structure of the DOM breaking how my code locates a specific WebElement.

Now in another method, I'm trying to use the Selenium method `text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute` but it requires a locator.

I've tried passing in the WebElement as the locator but it raises a TypeError exception.

`TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement`

How can I get information for the locator parameter from my previously located WebElement?

```
def add_city_filter(driver: WebDriver, city: str) -> None:
    city_filter: WebElement

    if not is_search_filter_box_visible(driver):
        click_show_filters_button(driver)

    city_filter = get_city_filter_field(driver)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(city_filter)).click()
    city_filter.send_keys(city)
    Utility.wait_for_network_inactivity(driver)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute(city_filter, "value", "")
    )

    if not has_applied_filter(driver, Filters.FilterOptions.City):
        raise Exception("Filter was not added")
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**:

You're sending a `WebElement` to a method which expects a locator. You'll need to write a custom wait to achieve the expected result

**Explanation**:

The `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute` expects you to share a `By` locator in order to find the element using `find_element()` method.

```py
def text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute(locator, attribute_, text_):
    """An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the
    element's attribute.
    locator, attribute, text
    """

    def _predicate(driver):
        try:
            element_text = driver.find_element(*locator).get_attribute(attribute_)
            if element_text is None:
                return False
            return text_ in element_text
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

    return _predicate
```

In order to achieve the same functionality for WebElement(s), you'll need to write your own wait which does the comparison minus the finding parts. One way to achieve this is as below :

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class attribute_to_be:
    def __init__(self, element, attribute, value):
        self.element = element
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element_value = self.element.get_attribute(self.attribute)
        return self.value in element_value

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://google.com")

sleep(2)

locator = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gb_t")
element = wait.until(attribute_to_be(locator, 'textContent', 'Gmail'))
print(element)
```

Here, it looks for the `textContent` attribute of the element located by the class `.gb_t` to be equal to Gmail. This throws an exception too if the attribute value is false and has exceeded the maximum wait.

Source:

- [Selenium HQ Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py)